# Custom Post type forgetting data

Tags: actions, post-meta

I just set up a custom post type, mostly following [this tutorial](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/).

I'm setting up things on my site now, doing a lot of CSS modifications and such, and every few minutes the post just forgets everything that's in the custom meta boxes.

I'm sure I've done something wrong in the add_action/update_post_meta section, but I don't know what it is, because I don't really understand the entirety of what the code does.

In any case, here's the entire thing:

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');

function portfolio_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('My Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}

register_taxonomy("portfolio_cat", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true));

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("media_meta", "Media", "media_meta", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
  add_meta_box("highlights_meta", "Highlights", "highlights_meta", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
  add_meta_box("main_meta", "Main", "main_meta", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
  add_meta_box("tabbed_meta", "Tabbed", "tabbed_meta", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
}


function media_meta(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $media_meta = $custom["media_meta"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Media:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="110" rows="5" name="media_meta"><?php echo $media_meta; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}

function highlights_meta(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $highlights_meta = $custom["highlights_meta"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Highlights:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="110" rows="5" name="highlights_meta"><?php echo $highlights_meta; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}

function main_meta(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $main_meta = $custom["main_meta"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Main:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="110" rows="5" name="main_meta"><?php echo $main_meta; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}

function tabbed_meta(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $tabbed_meta = $custom["tabbed_meta"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Tabbed:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="110" rows="5" name="tabbed_meta"><?php echo $tabbed_meta; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
  global $post;

  update_post_meta($post->ID, "media_meta", $_POST["media_meta"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "highlights_meta", $_POST["highlights_meta"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "main_meta", $_POST["main_meta"]);
  update_post_meta($post->ID, "tabbed_meta", $_POST["tabbed_meta"]);
}

add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");

function portfolio_edit_columns($columns){
  $columns = array(
    "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
    "title" => "Portfolio Title",
    "description" => "Description",
    "media_meta" => "Media",
    "highlights_meta" => "Highlights",
    "main_meta" => "Main",
    "tabbed_meta" => "Tabbed",
    "portfolio_cat" => "Portfolio Categories"
  );

  return $columns;
}
function portfolio_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;

  switch ($column) {
    case "description":
      the_excerpt();
      break;
    case "media_meta":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["media_meta"][0];
      break;
    case "highlights_meta":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["highlights_meta"][0];
      break;
    case "main_meta":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["main_meta"][0];
      break;
    case "tabbed_meta":
      $custom = get_post_custom();
      echo $custom["tabbed_meta"][0];
      break;
    case "portfolio_cat":
      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'portfolio_cat', '', ', ','');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to sift through your code for an answer (sorry), but I'd like to point out that you really should consider using a better naming scheme, functions like `admin_init()` have a REALLY high possibility of conflicting with other core or plugin functions.

Comment: Oh, that’s a really terrible tutorial. So many errors.

Comment: Yeah, agreed on both counts. It's a bad tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the function hooked onto `save_posts` you should make sure that you check that the action wasn't triggered by an auto-save routine. I suspect that the reason why the post 'forgets' the data is that the post auto-saves, and updates the post-meta with blank data.

To do this:

```
function save_details($post_id){
    //Make sure you check this isn't an autosave.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
         return;

    update_post_meta($post_id, "media_meta", $_POST["media_meta"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "highlights_meta", $_POST["highlights_meta"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "main_meta", $_POST["main_meta"]);
    update_post_meta($post_id, "tabbed_meta", $_POST["tabbed_meta"]);
}
```

I've had a quick glance at the tutorial. It seems to ignore best practice and security checks such as the following:

1. The function hooked on `save_posts` is given the argument `$post_id`
   (the post ID). You should use this rather than `global $post`.
2. **Prefix your functions**.  `save_details` is very generic, and if the WordPress core or another plug-in uses that function name, it'll crash your blog. This is particularly important for plugin developers. Prefix it with something unique: `my_name_save_details`. Same goes for the other functions.
3. Check user permissions. Use [`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) to verify that a user is allowed to be editing the post.
4. Uses nonces. In your metabox, add a nonce and verify it in `my_name_save_details`. This checks the data you're adding to your database really came from your metabox.([See Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce))
5. Perform other checks. `save_posts` fires every time a post or page is  saved/updated, but you only really want to be altering posts of your custom post type. It's not essential, but removes the possibility of upsets further down the line. You can use [`get_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) to help with this.

Comment: A side note: you can include multiple fields inside a metabox. I'd recommend taking a look at this [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for a 'best practise' example (it's not a tutorial though...). Hope this helps :D

Comment: For a minimal example see my [basic meta box](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Nav-Menu-Per-Post/blob/master/basic_meta_box.php).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Stephen Harris](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris) is excellent, but shows that rolling your own friendly custom fields can be a real pain. To do things securely and robustly you have to hold WordPress' hand quite a bit. I'll save my rant about how WordPress should do many of these things by default. Instead, I'll point you to [the Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which will help with everything in the above question.

The plugin has [nice documentation for each of the different types of fields provided](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/), and [handy code snippets for getting the data out and into your templates](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/code-examples/).

Best of all, it's free for everything you're trying to use it for.

This plugin isn't perfect for every site, but it's great for when you just want to add a few extra fields to a custom post type.

If you're interested in continuing with rolling your own friendly custom fields, [I highly recommend this article from .net magazine](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/user-friendly-custom-fields-meta-boxes-wordpress). It walks through the issues you're experiencing, and has helped me in the past.